# How to build scalable multi-application with ability to scale up certain app components?

Tags: java, spring, docker, architecture, scalability

I'm building app (Java, Spring) which reads list of "services" from single db and then listen on single REST endpoint and runs specified service (depending on request param) in single worker thread. I may also want to run certain "services" on more instances, and some only on several, because some services may be heavily used and some not. My goal is to make this application scalable through docker replication.

Typical use case - Services:

- 1x Service A
- 1x Service B
- 2x Service C
- 2x Service D
- 5x Service E

How to build systems like this, with ability to balance services between nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general question and there are many ways depending on your application. I'll try to answer it with some general thoughts about replication and cloud infrastructure.

**Which infrastructure do you prefer?**

- Commercial cloud (aws, google,...) provide everything (load balancing, replication ) for you
- Use kubernetes on your own hardware gives you the opportunity to define how many services should run on different nodes (servers) and the possibility to share data storage on different nodes
- You can implement your custom solution

**Do you have to replicate storage?**

While running multiple instances of "stateless" application services is quite easy, sharing databases across multiple nodes is more difficult. You could split your data storage (e.g. users of group a are on node a...) or have to duplicate every change in the database to all nodes (if you have many writes this reduces your performance)

**Load balancing**

If you have multiple nodes you should use a load balancer (e.g. an nginx instance) which is the entrypoint for every request that has no application logic but routes the request to the correct service. For a instanciated services the load balancer can route the requests evenly e.g. with a random function or by knowing the workload of each node (therefore every node has to provide its workload). If you want to handle it dynamically every service should have a route to detect the workload (e.g. /status) or you need a tool like cadvisor to detect the usage of a node. Maybe kubernetes is the better solution for that.

**Docker**

By dockerizing every element of your infrastructure you're generally on a good way to gain scalability. Every service e.g. your java backend, databases, load balancer... should be dockerized. Key question is again the storage which you would may have to replicate.

**Microservices**

A very popular pattern are microservices. Every service follows the pattern of separation of concerns. You won't have big databases as every service has his own rather small db. On the offside is the communication overhead, if it needs data from another service it will ask for it by interservice requests (therefore you have to implement a strict security policy e.g. jwts)

**Summary**

From my point of view and if you want to avoid aws&co i'd start by launching all services with the same database on the same node. E.g. run your sql or nosql db on the same node with their application services. Use a load balancer like nginx that routes all requests to your nodes. Dockerize everything and mount data with docker volumes. Upgrade your hardware if you're gaining the limit. If this won't fit use kubernetes.